# flex @ oracle open world 2009?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

2 years ago I red on jamesward's blog http://www.jamesward.com/blog/2007/11/12/oracle-chooses-flex-part-1/ something about oracle uses flex technology.

Does anyone know something about the progress? Were there still apps with flex at the oracle openworld?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle showed more Flex applications at OpenWorld 2009 this year.  Flex applications that were showed during keynotes and sessions include: My Oracle Support, Social CRM, Siebel Gadgets, Enterprise Manager, and various other demos.